# pip install RPi.GPIO on mac

Tags: installation, terminal, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to install RPi.GPIO on my macbook and I keep running into an error.

In the terminal I am writing:

`pip install Rpi.GPIO`

And I get the following output

[image: error]

How can I install this package on my computer?

Comment: Rpi.GPIO is designed specifically for the raspberry-pi so you can't install on a Mac or PC. You'll need to emulate it if you want to run python scripts on the Mac. Here's a similar question with some answers: [gpio library on windows while developing](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/34119/144439)